# How to create Stored Procedure in DB2 for UPDATE operation for all Data Types?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, sql-update

I want to update all records from my table using Stored Procedure but, I am getting error.

This is my Table Structure -

```
create table DataTypes (smallint_1 SMALLINT,integer_1 INTEGER,bigint_1 BIGINT,float_1 
FLOAT,decimal_1 DECIMAL,varchar_1 VARCHAR(50),char_1 CHAR(20),boolean_1 BOOLEAN,date_1 
DATE,time_1 TIME,timestamp_1 TIMESTAMP,real_1 REAL, double_1 DOUBLE, clob_1 CLOB(5M),blob_1 
BLOB(5M))
```

Below is my Stored Procedure -

```
@delimiter %%%;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "DB2INST1"."update_3" (IN smallint_1 SMALLINT, In integer_1 
INTEGER, In bigint_1 BIGINT, In float_1 FLOAT, In decimal_1 DECIMAL, In varchar_1 VARCHAR(50), 
In char_1 CHAR(20), In boolean_1 BOOLEAN, In date_1 DATE, In time_1 TIME, In timestamp_1 
TIMESTAMP, In real_1 REAL, In double_1 DOUBLE, In clob_1 clob(5M), In blob_1 blob(5M)) 
SPECIFIC update_3
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
update datatypes set smallint_1= update_3.smallint_1, bigint_1= update_3.bigint_1, float_1= 
update_3.float_1, decimal_1= update_3.decimal_1, varchar_1= update_3.varchar_1, char_1= 
update_3.char_1, boolean_1= update_3.boolean_1, date_1= update_3.date_1, time_1= 
update_3.time_1, timestamp_1= update_3.timestamp_1, real_1= update_3.real_1, double_1= 
update_3.double_1, clob_1= update_3.clob_1, blob_1= update_3.blob_1 where integer_1= 
update_3.integer_1;
END;%%%
@delimiter;%%%
```

Getting this error when I try to create stored procedure -

```
[Code: -206, SQL State: 42703]  "UPDATE_3.SMALLINT_1" is not valid in the context where it is 
used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.28.11
```

Please help me with the correct Stored Procedure to UPDATE all values from my table.

Comment: Object names between `"` are case sensitive, other names are upper cased before the object name is verified. So `"update_3"` is different from `update_3` which is the same as `UPDATE_3`

Comment: Also, I don't think you can qualify parameter names with the procedure name as you're trying to do. Don't name the procedure parameters the same as the table columns.

Comment: Look at the [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/uV-SnbcU).

Comment: @Mark Barinstein and NFGL can anyone of you answer my question ? so I can accept your answer for this question.

Comment: @Mark Barinstein your example solved my issue. My procedure is working perfectly.